# What is the best way to code a D-Pad in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I have looked all over the internet for this. I was wondering what would be the best way to code a D-Pad that moves a character around the screen? This would be extremely helpful if someone answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the joystick, google SneakyInput. its then a case of responding to the direction changes, and either moving the camera, or the character.

```
CGPoint scaledVelocity= ccpMult(sneakyInputJoystick.velocity, 480.0f);
CGPoint newPosition = ccp(aNode.position.x + scaledVelocity.x * deltaTime, tempNode.position.y + scaledVelocity.y * deltaTime);
[aNode setPosition:newPosition];
```

Comment: How do I make it respond to the direction changes?

Comment: How far have you got with sneakyInput? once you have the joystick added to the game layer, you need to schedule updates, and then in the update method, you need to apply the transform to the layer/sprite you want to move. I will post some code in the answer above for applying the movement.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like this better.

[Cocos2D UI](http://brenwill.com/2010/cocos2d-ui-controls/)